# I have a modal segue between viewcontrollers. I want it to completely restart the loading of the viewcontrollers when I move between them

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, viewcontroller

For instance, if I press 'back' on the navigation bar to go back to the first viewcontroller, then the variables don't get reset - they stay at whatever value they got to before I pressed back. So then if I go back to the second viewcontroller again, it doesn't completely restart everything.

I could just programmatically reset everything in viewDidLoad everytime, but I'm wondering if there is a simple method or something already made for this.

It's all done in storyboards so I don't have code to show.

Answer (score 1):

> I could just programmatically reset everything in viewDidLoad everytime

Actually, this wouldn't work. `viewDidLoad` is only called once per instance.

You probably don't want to do this, since most users will be confused and annoyed by the behavior. But if you're sure you want to, you could:

1. Reset everything in `viewWillAppear:`, which will get called every time, although this will also get called if the user leaves and then re-enters your app
2. Use the back button's behavior to trigger a method call that will reset the variables to whatever you want. For example, you could do this in `prepareForSegue:` using the delegation or notification patterns, depending on what's appropriate in your app.

> I'm wondering if there is a simple method or something already made for this.

It shouldn't be that hard, but there's no built-in "reset view" behavior, since this is almost always considered undesirable.

Comment: When I press back and then go back to the second viewcontroller, viewDidLoad DOES run again, I can see it with breakpoints. So maybe it reinstantiates it when you use modal segues?

Comment: @fefewaffeaf, viewDidLoad should not run again if you're actually going back to a previous view controller. You must be instantiating a new one instead. How are you  "going back"?

Answer (score -1):

Use `-viewWillAppear:`, `-viewDidAppear:`, `-viewDidDisappear`, and/or `-viewWillDisappear:`.